# Joomla and Google Analytics with advanced options

Tags: joomla, google-analytics

I want to insert google analytics tracking code in my joomla site.

so i registered in the official site of google and saw there is an advanced tab with three more options than standard.

Do i have to check "i want to track dynamic pages" and "i want to track php pages"?
Do these options provide me better results or they are necessary for a dynamic site based on php like joomla?

Also where do i place the tracking code? Because of some bugs some say it is better just after the  tag whereas other say just before the  tag.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. General SEO advice: with Joomla you don't need to track pages dynamically, if you want, you can turn on SEF and use robots.txt, ror.xml and sitemap.xml (the first and last files are very important to google).
2. I also recommend on using [Google webmaster tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/) to update Google whenever you post a new article as well as to check if there are crawling errors and remove "bad" URLs from google.
3. Like I commented on the other answer, tracking code should be located [*just before the closing  tag for your web page*](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview#trackingCodePlacement) - I recommend on **placing the tracking code in the template!** (even though you can copy and paste it separately into each article - this option should be done only on rare cases that you need to pass different parameters to GA from different articles.

**Update:**
Regarding your comment: yes, if you go to the "admin" section, then to "tracking code" you'll see the following option:

[image]

All it does is provide a different way of including the tracking code in your pages. I got to admit that I didn't use this option with a few Joomla and WP websites I've dealt with, and it still works totally fine. But if Google recommend on doing so - by all means go ahead and do it!

Comment: when you go to edit your tracking code somewhere there has a tab that says advanced. If you check it then it shows two more options :_i want to track dynamic pages_ and _is it php page_ (or something like that). Are you aware of these options? Should i use them for Joomla site or should add the standard code? I really can't find any information about joomla and these options.

Comment: i read somewhere that these options are for a more precise analytics report (because of the dynamic generated content of joomla). i followed the instructions [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=431&t=499232&view=next) but it didn't work. i don't have much experience to search it more so i did the standard installation. If you sometime manage to understand something further i would appreciate to share it with me.

Comment: I don't think it should be more precise, there are other kinds of dynamic-pages (JSP for example) that doesn't require such special settings. I would just go with the regular settings - it works fine for me. That said, if I'll find anything new - I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this source on [setting up GA](http://svhostingblog.com/guides/google-analytics-step-by-step-basic-setup-guide/), it is important for PHP websites that you include the google tracking script at the bottom of the page before the `</BODY>` tag. I'm struggling to find any information that would give relevance to the questions you have mentioned above, beyond the fact that choosing different checkboxes shows you different instructions to setting up your script.

Comment: no i don't think it is just for the type and language. it must be something for accuracy in tracking the subpages or something

Comment: After looking some more, the selection you choose just seem to dictate the instructions for setting up your script. I work in .NET and I have never needed to ensure that the script is at the bottom of the `<BODY>` section, perhaps this is a PHP specific requirement.

Comment: @JDandChips it has nothing to do with PHP/.NET. This is Google-Analytics recommended settings: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingOverview#trackingCodePlacement

Comment: @alfasin that is the point I was originally trying to make. I was merely reflecting on my experiences in .NET and trying to give miako a different opinion on setting up GA